# jQuery - keydown / keypress /keyup ENTERKEY detection?

Tags: jquery

Trying to get jQuery to detect enter input, but space and other keys are detected, enter isn't detected.  What's wrong below:

```
$("#entersomething").keyup(function(e) {
    alert("up");
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code==13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (code == 32 || code == 13 || code == 188 || code == 186) {
        $("#displaysomething").html($(this).val());
});

<input id="entersomething" />
<div id="displaysomething"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeRrv/

Comment: for mobile support and brevity use `event.key` instead of `event.which/keyCode` (they are deprecated)

Comment: yes, it's been almost 10 years since i asked this question. glad to know jquery is still around and evolving!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("#entersomething").keyup(function(e){ 
    var code = e.key; // recommended to use e.key, it's normalized across devices and languages
    if(code==="Enter") e.preventDefault();
    if(code===" " || code==="Enter" || code===","|| code===";"){
        $("#displaysomething").html($(this).val());
    } // missing closing if brace
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="entersomething" type="text" /> <!-- put a type attribute in -->
<div id="displaysomething"></div>
```

Comment: doh!! btw is there an IDE you'd recommend that can check for braces? tried using aptana, but having difficulty adapt to it and it doesn't have a shortcut for in-ide preview!

Comment: If you are on OSX then Textmate wins hands down for me. Zend Studio and Aptana were nice and I'm sure that you can manually add shortcuts/hotkeys to do what you'd like???

Interesting about `event.which`, never knew that before:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes

Comment: @balupton - I should add that `event.which` is normalized in jQuery, in the `jQuery.event.fix` function

Comment: Do note that `which` is now being deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: @Juxhin is right on the deprecation notice. Historically, IE started it with `event.keyCode` then the --moz and --webkit family pushed `event.which`. Both of which are now **DEPRECATED** along with `event.charCode`. The only option that's left is `event.key` but --moz family does not currently support it.

Comment: we now have a lot of mobile/touch keyboards and we can no longer trust arbitrary key codes such as 13/186. in other words - stop using `event.which/keyCode` and start using `event.key`

Comment: @oriadam feel free to edit the answer to provide the now better option.

Comment: @oriadam: Where is this documented? I don't see it in [the API](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: @Zaz the use of `ev.key` instead of `ev.keyCode` is related to [the browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), not jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

update: nowadays we have mobile and custom keyboards and we cannot continue trusting these arbitrary key codes such as 13 and 186. in other words, stop using `event.which`/`event.keyCode` and start using `event.key`:

```
if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "ArrowUp" || event.key === "ArrowDown")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll struggle with keyup event - as it first triggers keypress - and you won't be able to stop the propagation of the second one if you want to exclude the Enter Key.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Sparkle includes a custom event for this. The source can be seen here:
http://github.com/balupton/jquery-sparkle/blob/master/scripts/resources/jquery.events.js

Here is a demo http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-sparkle/demo/#event-enter