# How to assign enter key the same function as click?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have the **enter key** perform the same task as when a user clicks the button (see jquery). However, when I tried "keyup" and other event handlers, I couldn't get it working correctly. Any ideas on the simpliest way to do this?

Thanks for your patience, and help.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LightYearsAway/qg8f3q37/3/

HTML

```
<h3>Needs</h3>
<input type="text" id="need-input" placeholder="enter text">
<button id="btn1">Need it!</button>
<ul id="need-list">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // click button, add to list

  $("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("#need-list").append($("<li>", { text: $("#need-input").val()
      }));
  });

  // click list item to hide

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
      $(this).slideUp();
  });

});
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want the user to be able to press enter while in the text box, and have it do what clicking the button would do?

Comment: put it inside a `form` so that enter actvates the submit event.

Comment: @Zack: Yes, you are right; I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Have you done any research? This is obviously a duplicate.

Comment: @CodeGodie: Of course, but for those of us who are just beginning to learn, duplicates are not so "obvious."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#need-input").on("keydown", function(e) { 
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        $("#btn1").click() 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qg8f3q37/4/

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Rather than answering and creating dupliactes on SO,  you need to point him to the duplicate sources.

Comment: Wow! Short and simple. Any ideas on how to clear the text area so the user wouldn't have to delete each entry? (Just curious...)

Comment: @Steran simply do `$(this).val('');` after, inside the if statement. https://jsfiddle.net/qg8f3q37/5/

Answer (score -1):

I BELIEVE THIS COULD HELP YOU

[How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Rather than answering and creating dupliactes on SO, you need to point him to the duplicate sources

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#need-input").keyup(function (e) {
    var code = e.which; // recommended to use e.which, it's normalized across browsers
    if (code == 13) e.preventDefault();
    if (code == 32 || code == 13 || code == 188 || code == 186) {
        $("#need-list").append($("<li>", {
            text: $("#need-input").val()
        }));
    }
});
```

From answer: ([jQuery - keydown / keypress /keyup ENTERKEY detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462995/jquery-keydown-keypress-keyup-enterkey-detection))

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Rather than answering and creating dupliactes on SO, you need to point him to the duplicate sources